# Java and other clients for WCF RESTful Services

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, rest

I am wanting to expose some data service endpoints for internal application use and am debating on WCF REST as a possible solution.   What are my options for other languages/platforms as clients?  Keeping in mind that I need to service Java, Python and .Net clients.

Essentially, I want to be able to demonstrate a single point of organization data access for multiple clients, and feel that the REST toolkit, especially with JSON could work very well.  Being able to address multiple clients with a single data access layer would be a really good thing.

I feel that WCF + REST is probably the best solution for this on the server-side, but want to demonstrate the other languages working against the services.  As a point of really selling the option for use beyond my developer group within the organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP, JSON, POX ( plain old XML ) coexist endpoints for WCF services would solve your problem.

Check out the first result (my blog) after seaching keywords on 
"SOAP, JSON, POX ( plain old XML ) coexist"

It contains a sample project as well.

Comment: for those looking, <a href="http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html">here is the article link</a>.